# How to use Shapely for subtracting two polygons

Tags: python, shapely, set-difference

I am not really sure how to explain this but I have 2 polygons, Polygon1 and Polygon2. These polygons overlapped with each other. How to do I get Polygon2 using Shapely without the **P** from Polygon1.

[image]

Comment: So you want to the the remainder of `Polygon2` after subtracting the overlapping areas?

Comment: @Torxed yes, exactly.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You are looking for a [difference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complement_(set_theory)#Relative_complement). In Shapely you can calculate it either by using a [`difference`](https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/latest/manual.html#object.difference) method or by simply subtracting* one polygon from another:

```
from shapely.geometry import Polygon

polygon1 = Polygon([(0.5, -0.866025), (1, 0), (0.5, 0.866025), (-0.5, 0.866025), (-1, 0), (-0.5, -0.866025)])
polygon2 = Polygon([(1, -0.866025), (1.866025, 0), (1, 0.866025), (0.133975, 0)])
```

[image]

```
difference = polygon2.difference(polygon1)  # or difference = polygon2 - polygon1
```

[image]

See [docs](https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/latest/manual.html#set-theoretic-methods) for more set-theoretic methods.

---

<sup>*This feature is not documented. See issue on GitHub: [Document set-like properties](https://github.com/Toblerity/Shapely/issues/903).</sup>