# Polygon extraction,

Tags: python-3.x, polygon

I have two polygons with coordinates `[x,y,x,y,x,y,x,y,x,y,x,y]`, and `[m,n,m,n,m,n,m,n,m,n]`.
For example

`poly1 = [4,3,4,5,3,5,3,11,5,11,7,13,10,11,11,11,11,8,9,4,6,4,6,3]`

`poly2 = [7,13,10,11,10,9,6,9,6,10,5,10,5,11]`

The second polygon is located inside the first one like shown in the image.

[image]

I have to extract small polygon from large one and get its coordinates in the same format.

can anyone help?

Comment: What do you mean by "extract"? Perhaps, "subtract"? And by the way, the green polygon is _not_ inside the red polygon.

Comment: Do you have any code?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use Shapely for subtracting two polygons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61930060/how-to-use-shapely-for-subtracting-two-polygons)

Comment: presumably you mean `[x1,y1,x2,y2,...xn,yn]` and similarly for the other polygon...